# Using ML to detect what classical cipher the ciphertext is encrypted with

Tags: classical-cipher, machine-learning

I was considering creating an ML project where it is fed some ciphertext by any classical cipher and would return possible ciphers that encrypted the text. I would have to create a sizeable dataset for it so I was wondering if this idea is relatively feasible before I attempt it.

Comment: Yes possible. Should be a good exercise for ML learners..